# How to access-protect to data on my Google Compute Engine VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I want to work with sensitive data that should not be seen by other members on a specific VM instance in GCP that my organization has contracted.

Usually, if I just set up a VM instance, other members of your organization are free to create a user to connect to her VM with SSH and have sudo privileges.
So, I'm wondering if I shouldn't have sensitive data inside the VM.

Q. Is there a way to prevent other users from accessing my VM instance data?
Q. Is [the OS login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) suitable for the above purposes?If there is a simpler and more typical method, I would like to adopt it.

I currently have the role of "editor" on the GCP project.

Thanks.

Comment: More fundamentally, do you have any guarantees from Google that stuff you upload there will not be shared e.g. with their support personnel?

Comment: tripleee, thanks for your comment.

I have an explicit Term of Service agreement with Google Cloud staff, so sharing data with them is not an issue.

The issue is that I am not allowed to share that data in an environment where my colleagues can see it.